# How to fit column/row table image content in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, kotlin, dart, row

I have this little project to fit a 9 images into column/row table with flutter the problem is that the images are presented out of the screen

I wanted it to be like this:

[image: I wanted it to be like this]

This is the code

```
 return MaterialApp(
          home: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
                body: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset('images/1.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        Image.asset('images/2.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        Image.asset('images/3.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset('images/4.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        Image.asset('images/5.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        Image.asset('images/6.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset('images/7.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        Image.asset('images/8.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                        Image.asset('images/9.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        );
```

This is the result:

[image: this is the resulte]

Comment: Add yourI Image widget inside `Expanded()` like-> `Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/3.png', fit: BoxFit.fill),),`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using Expanded widget-

```
return MaterialApp(
          home: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
                body: Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/1.png',fit: BoxFit.fill), flex:1),
                        Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/2.png',fit: BoxFit.fill), flex:1),
                        Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/3.png',fit: BoxFit.fill), flex:1),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/4.png',fit: BoxFit.fill), flex:1),
                        Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/5.png',fit: BoxFit.fill), flex:1),
                        Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/6.png',fit: BoxFit.fill), flex:1),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/7.png',fit: BoxFit.fill), flex:1),
                        Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/8.png',fit: BoxFit.fill), flex:1),
                        Expanded(child:Image.asset('images/9.png',fit: BoxFit.fill), flex:1),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        );
```

Let me know if it works...

Comment: I realized that my code had some errors. I fixed them. Please recheck it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use grid view instead of column/row

```
return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: GridView.count(
            crossAxisSpacing: 5,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10,
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('lib/food.jpg'),
              Image.asset('lib/food.jpg'),
              Image.asset('lib/food.jpg'),
              Image.asset('lib/food.jpg'),
              Image.asset('lib/food.jpg'),
              Image.asset('lib/food.jpg'),
              Image.asset('lib/food.jpg'),
              Image.asset('lib/food.jpg'),
              Image.asset('lib/food.jpg'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: didnt want to use gridview thanks anway